# Mysterious UI glitch ocean wave look

Tags: mac, display, gpu

This started recently and I can't see much I took this picture and am now on my phone. A few apps have this fun new UI, but I don't think it's actually on purpose. 
[image]

This just started happening recently with only some apps. I was not doing anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on?

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question? Please add what you were doing before this issue came up and also add steps you have tried. It would be helpful if you can describe whether you can boot Single User Mode (Reboot and Command + S during startup) and whether you can access macOS Recovery (Reboot and Command + R during startup).